# how can I get a new column order sequence when type is only service

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have this transaction table how can I get a new column order sequence when type is only service and product.

Question

| id | Type | Date | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Member | 2021-02-24 | 4 |
| 1 | product | 2021-01-03 | 2 |
| 2 | service | 2022-04-21 | 5 |
| 1 | product | 2021-02-01 | 3 |
| 2 | service | 2022-02-16 | 3 |
| 1 | Member | 2022-02-03 | 6 |
| 1 | Service | 2021-10-23 | 5 |
| 2 | product | 2022-01-03 | 2 |
| 1 | service | 2020-12-16 | 1 |
| 2 | product | 2022-03-30 | 4 |
| 2 | service | 2021-12-01 | 1 |
| 1 | Member | 2022-04-03 | 7 |

Result

| id | Type | Date | Sequence | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Member | 2021-02-24 | 4 | Null |
| 1 | product | 2021-01-03 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | service | 2022-04-21 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | product | 2021-02-01 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | service | 2022-02-16 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | Member | 2022-02-03 | 6 | Null |
| 1 | Service | 2021-10-23 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | product | 2022-01-03 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | service | 2020-12-16 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | product | 2022-03-30 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | service | 2021-12-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Member | 2022-04-03 | 7 | Null |

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Please don't tag databases not involved

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Type IN ('service','product') THEN Sequence END Newcolumn
FROM T
```

Comment: Thank you I know that but I want the new column to be in order of rows not the same as he sequence.

Comment: Ok but your expected results seem like use his sequence to  create new column ,could you provide some expect results from your sample data ?

Comment: Just did if you look at row 7, you will see that sequence is 5 but expected result is 4

Comment: @babyfaze16 Ok I see but why does only row 7 get a different value instead of all? what's the logic?

Comment: I only want my new order of sequence to only count when type is  product or service. Others will be null won't count.

Comment: @babyfaze16 I mean why did only `Just did if you look at row 7, you will see that sequence is 5 but expected result is 4 ` instead of for all type is product or service

Comment: no reason it is just a sample, I can add more sample if that would make it better.